# Let $y''(t) + 6y'(t) = K $. For what $K$ does $\lim_{t\to\infty} y(t) = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Consider the equation $y''(t) + 6y'(t)  = K $. For what $K$ do all solutions of the equation satisfy $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} y(t) = 0$?

I solved the equation and got

$$y = C_1  + C_2 e^{-6t} +  \frac{K}{6}t.$$

Since $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \frac{K}{6}t = \infty$, it seems to me that the only possible $K$ would be zero. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Yes, $K$ and $C_1$ must be $0$. $C_2$ is arbitary. (You should also mention that a negative $K$ leads to limit $-\infty$).